# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number' .ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm stuck in learning Typescript language and need some explanations. The problem is that variable named as `this.value` is never assigned as undefined due `isValid` function check it. How to make typescript understand it?

```
export const isValid = (n: any) => n && n > 0 && n < 10;

class Test {
    value: number;
    constructor(value?: number) {
        /*
        Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
        */
        this.value = isValid(value) ? value : -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, the type checker does not look at the implementation of called functions, only their signature. Therefore, the typechecker for the constructor does not know that `isValid` will only return true if `n` is a number.

You can either inline the code of `isValid` into the constructor:

```
constructor(value) {
  this.value = value && value > 0 && value < 10 ? value : -1;
}
```

or extend the function signature of `isValid` with a [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
export function isValid(n: any): n is number {
  return n && n > 0 && n < 10;
}
```

Comment: That's I'm looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As the `value` in constructor is optional. its type is `number | undefined`, you need to cast it as number when you are assigning it:

```
 this.value = isValid(value) ? value as number : -1 ;
```

Comment: Yes I can, but it does not look safe. What if I change IsValid function expression in the future and forget to remove `as number` cast.. Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: `as number` is for the `value` and not for the `isValid(value)`. Once way to do so is remove `value` as optional.