# error TS2322: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm at least trying to develop a chatbot for an exhibition
the error is as follows:

> src/app/chat/chat.component.ts:32:9 - error TS2322: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> 32         this.message = undefined;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~

and the section of code is seen below

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IChat } from '../interfaces/ichat';
import { ChatService } from '../services/chat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  chats: IChat[] = [];
  message: string;
  sending: boolean;

  constructor(private _chatService: ChatService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to pusher's event
    this._chatService.getChannel().bind('chat', data => {
      if (data.email === this._chatService.user.email) {
        data.isMe = true;
      }
      this.chats.push(data);
    });
  }

  sendMessage(message: string) {
    this.sending = true;
    this._chatService.sendMessage(message)
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.message = undefined;
        this.sending = false;
      }, err => {
        this.sending = false;
      } );
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number' .ts(2322)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64566666/type-undefined-is-not-assignable-to-type-number-ts2322)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign an empty string :

```
this.message = "";
```

instead of

```
this.message = undefined;
```

or define the `message` property like :

```
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  chats: IChat[] = [];
  message: string | undefined;
```

then you could assign `undefined` to it `this.message = undefined;`